# PyVisa won't find my GIPB port

Tags: python

I tried downloading the PyVisa module with the NI Visa libraries to find the GPIB port and address of the Agilent E4350B but no matter what I try it won't find it. I have a short code:

```
import visa
rm = visa.ResourceManager()
print(rm.open_resource())
```

But all it prints out is

```
('ASRL1::INSTR', 'ASRL2::INSTR')
```

I try to just open it anyways with the address I have it set at:

```
rm.open_resource('GPIB0::5::INSTR')
```

But it gives me this:

```
pyvisa.errors.VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_LIBRARY_NFOUND (-1073807202): A code library required by VISA could not be located or loaded.
```

I am running the same bit versions of Python and PyVISA. Can anyone tell me why it's not finding it?

Comment: One source [unable to get ResourceManager in Pyvisa 1.5 to work with Python 2.7.8](https://github.com/hgrecco/pyvisa/issues/73) suggests a problem with VISA rather than PyVISA and suggests installing [NI-VISA 5.4.1](http://www.ni.com/download/ni-visa-5.4.1/4626/en/). Are you able to provide more debug output?

Comment: No, every time I write "python -m visa info" for debug information but it gives me "/usr/bin/python: No module named visa" even though i have downloaded the module. @JonathonOgden

Comment: I have installed NI-VISA 5.4.1 and I am still getting the same error. It wont find the instrument that I am trying to use. @JonathonOgden

Comment: Can you call `rm.list_resources()` and if so, what output do you get from that?

Comment: I get 'u'ASRL3::INSTR''. The GPIB address set on my instrument is 5, so I want 'GPIB0::5::INSTR' but that wont show up, @JonathonOgden

Comment: I see, and it's not registering your Agilent in the resource list (I'd expect to see the GPIB address for it in the list). It's registering a device on a serial port. How is your instrument plugged in exactly? Via a GPIB interface or controller?